# How can I successfully use raw query in typeorm with using ANY clause?

Tags: sql, typescript, orm, typeorm

I have postgres datasource with me and I am trying to run a raw sql query for fetching users which match list of user_ids.

```
const query = `SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "user_id" = ANY($1)`
const results = await this.manager.query(query, [user_ids]);
```

The above query doesn't return any results and I know there is data with corresponding user_ids. Please help ?